Log-normal mean reversion SDE
I study the Tataru-Fisher 2003 LSV model (implemented in the Bbg terminal for FX exotics pricing), the volatility has the following dynamics : $$dV_t = \kappa (1 - V_t) dt + \xi V_t dB_t $$
In the paper it is said that this dynamics is log normal :

We have chosen a lognormal process for the volatility process... the volatility process Vt
cannot reach zero

and they use the log-normality of this process for describing the whole study of the model.
I've tried to show this log-normality by applying Ito's formula to $ln(V_t)$ :
$$d(ln(V_t)) = \big(\kappa(\frac{1}{V_t} - 1) - \frac{\xi^2}{2}\big)dt + \xi dB_t$$
So i don't get apparent normal law for $ln(V_t)$ process.
Moreover i try to test normality of the process by doing an Euler Scheme diffusion and basic adequation statistics tests don't reject normality assumption. I read in some papers here or here that this process is called log-normal mean reversion.
In the first source they caracterize the log-normality diffusion as something where $$d \langle V \rangle _t = V_t^2 \xi^2 dt$$
Do you know how to prove log-normality of such process ? Or at least strict positivity.

Log normality only comes from the fact that the process dVt depends on Vt.

How can we show that ? I can't see direct link between what you call "dVt depends on Vt" and law of the process Vt. How do you state rigorously this last sentence btw ?

Hi: What you wrote at the top for the dynamics is a version of geometric brownian motion. That's why you get the log normaility. See this for  details. https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~dodso013/docs/GBM-primer.pdf

Sorry i don't understand what you call "a version of gbm" ? For me the definition of a GBM is the solution to the SDE $dX_t = X_t(\mu dt + \sigma dW_t) $. But here for $dV_t$ the drift isn't factorizable by $V_t$.

Hi Justin: are you talking about the $\kappa (1 - V_t) dt$ term ? and comparing it to the $X_t \mu dt$ term ? It's late and I'm having trouble following. I could have made a mistake somewhere ?

Justin: Assuming I'm correct in what you're comparing, you can multiply the first term out so you get the $V_t$ by itself. As far as $\kappa dt$ term, I'm not an SDE guy by any stretch, but that term is deterministic so you are correct that it presents a division issue algebraically but it should not play a role in the derivation for log normality.

HI Justin: I was hoping that someone would have chimed in because my comment was far from helpful. I haven't had time to do much digging but I guess it's possible that one might get a shifted log normal because of the extra $dt$ term but now I'm guessing which I don't want to do. So, take my previous comments with a grain of salt and maybe provide another reference because I googled using  the "Tataru Fisher 2003" and it didn't lead to anything very useful. This is on the shifted lognormal. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379980/understanding-the-shifted-log-normal-distribution
